# ProtocolError when trying to connect cassandra with python

Tags: python, cassandra

I have cassandra running on a VM on 9042, using nginx it has been mapped to a subdomain mysub.original.com, which is a https, when trying to connect using below code:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

CASSANDRA_DB_HOST="mysub.original.com"
CASSANDRA_DB_PORT = 443
CASSANDRA_DB_KEYSPACE = "test"
table_name = "test_tab"

def read_cassandra_table(host, port, keyspace, table):
    cluster = Cluster([host], port=port,protocol_version=4)
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace)

    session.shutdown()
    cluster.shutdown()



read_cassandra_table(CASSANDRA_DB_HOST, CASSANDRA_DB_PORT, CASSANDRA_DB_KEYSPACE, table_name)
```

got the below error:

Tried with multiple cassandra-drivers but error remains same, passing `protocol_version=4` or removing it also did'nt worked.

```
python test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/poc/latest_abc_backend/abc-backend/test.py", line 101, in <module>
    read_cassandra_table(CASSANDRA_DB_HOST, CASSANDRA_DB_PORT, CASSANDRA_DB_KEYSPACE, table_name)
  File "/home/poc/latest_abc_backend/abc-backend/test.py", line 87, in read_cassandra_table
    session = cluster.connect(keyspace)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/poc/updated_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 1690, in connect
    self.control_connection.connect()
  File "/home/poc/updated_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3488, in connect
    self._set_new_connection(self._reconnect_internal())
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/poc/updated_venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 3533, in _reconnect_internal
    raise NoHostAvailable("Unable to connect to any servers", errors)
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'155.69.11.95:443': ProtocolError('This version of the driver does not support protocol version 72')})
```

Comment: You did not add what version of Cassandra server & python driver package [run `pip list` or `pip freeze` to find out] you've installed so it is not possible to triage this question. Please update your original question with those details. Also, you mentioned the server JVM process is running at `9042` but your program is using `443` as port which also need to be updated. If you cluster has encryption turned on, you need to use the appropriate connection properties in your program. Thanks. It is also advisable to use only 1 session across your application instance. opening and closing is costly